# Adding a magnet link to MonoTorrent

Tags: c#, magnet-uri, monotorrent

I have a magnet link and I am trying to create a TorrentManager by using the constructor for magnetlinks, but Visual Studio keeps telling me that it has invalid arguments. What am I doing wrong?

```
j="magnet:?xt=urn:btih"+myMagnet;
string save = @"C:\Users\Jamie\Downloads";
TorrentSettings torrentSettings = new TorrentSettings(0,10,1000,0);
TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(MonoTorrent.InfoHash.FromMagnetLink(j),save,    torrentSettings, save);
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , your question is vague, and you aren't telling us what the error message is

Comment: The error I am getting is pretty vague. All it says is that "Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager.TorrentManager(MonoTorrent.Common.Torrent, string, MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentSettings, string)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Jamie\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Web Scrubber\Web Scrubber\Form1.cs 79 42 Web Scrubber"